# Why is the 'Named Domain Class' tool missing in the DSL Designer category in the toolbox?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, dsl-tools

I have the Domain-Specific development with VS DSL Tools book by Cook, Jones, et.all

The book and various tutorials online mention a NamedDomainClass tool that should be present in the DSL Designer toolbox. I have installed VS 2010 beta 2 on Win XP - however this tool is missing in the toolbox.
I've created a project using the Minimal project template as mentioned in the book. I have 12 tools showing up including the Domain Class tool.

I've searched online and apparently no one else has this problem.

- Can someone confirm that it's missing
  in VS 2010 Beta 2?
- If not how can I get it
  to show up ?
- Is there any way in which I can add a Domain class instance and tweak it so that it becomes a Named Domain Class? The book mentions that there is some must-be-unique validation and serialization changes that are done by the NamedDomainClass tool.

I've tried 'Choose Items' context menu on the DSL Designer category. These tools apparently are added dynamically ; do not show up in the lists on the dialog that comes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered in the same post on the Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Domain-Specific Languages (DSL) & Modeling Tools Extensibility forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dslvsarchx/thread/a2221648-6e92-49ba-b223-8df98e2cdfdd

> I have confirmed that the Named Domain
>   Class has no longer existed in the
>   toolbox. It exists in the VS 2008's
>   toolbox.
>
> You can create a Named Domain Class in
>   VS 2010 by:
>   1. Add a Domain Class and diagram
>   2. Add a DomainProperty and named it as "Name"
>   3. In the Name DomainProperty's propertes, change "Is Element Name" to
>   true
>
> Hope it helps.
>
> Hongye Sun [MSFT]
>
> FYI this was a **bug in the SDK for Beta
>   2**. It has now been fixed.
>
> Regards, Duncan [MSFT]

Comment: Yeah it was my pairing partner who duplicated this question in the DSL Forums (since we were not getting any answers here - seems like a niche area). Forgot to update the original post (+15 for doing that for me. Thanks!)